# How to work with small components

Tags: soldering, circuit-design, prototyping

I want to test this [IC](http://www.mouser.se/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/FDC2114RGHT/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMs3uAJYYmvlK7b%252bKRLIK4f1XKmzmzd9VujmIheo%252bMWrTw%3D%3D) and therefor I need to implement a LC tank with really small components. Is there a trick how to properly solder those parts together? Especially for prototyping, where I might have to exchange parts from time to time.

Can I solder them somehow on universal PCBs?

I don't know the technical term for those kind of small components:[inductor](http://uk.farnell.com/wurth-elektronik/7447669118/inductor-18uh-10-0-7a-24mhz-1812/dp/2493211?aa=true&ost=inductance&vw=&categoryId=700000005466&eq=N%3D219438%2B2031%26amp%3BNtk%3Ddesc_pn%26amp%3BNtt%3Dinductance%26amp%3BNtx%3Drel%2Bgensearch_store_specific%252cstatic%2528P_STORE_MARKETING_RANK_FARNELL_UK%252cascending%2529%2Bmode%2Bmatchpartialmax%26amp%3BNty%3D1%26amp%3BNtpc%3D1%26amp%3BNtpr%3D1%26amp%3BD%3Dinductance*%26amp%3BDn%3D2031%2B2031%26amp%3BDx%3Dmode%2Bmatchall&searchView=table&iscrfnonsku=false), [capacitor](http://uk.farnell.com/kemet/cbr02c330f9gac/capacitor-rf-33pf-6-3v-0201/dp/2612596)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a QFN package.  You really need a PC board for those.  The pads are too close together and have too little area for soldering wires to them to be feasible.

QFN packages are really meant for reflow soldering, not manual with a soldering iron.  For manual one-off use, a hot air soldering station is best.  If you are doing this professionally or this is a commercial product, get a hot air station.

If you really need to use a soldering iron, then extend the pads a good ways past the part, like 20 mils or more.  That way there is a place for the soldering iron tip to touch the pad and the pin of the part simultaneously.

Comment: you could use [QFN to DIP small PCB adapter boards](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Chip-Quik/PA0061/?qs=gjT6naH6P5JHRO8OF2kqoA%3D%3D&gclid=CMSl88KI79ECFYO4wAodZ1cPig) for quick prototyping. This will allow you to use a universal board with larger L C components.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a quick solution then you are far better off starting with a pre made development board.
http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/FDC2114EVM/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvNM%2fd3q5fCVzBrFaRB3C8F1tKLhQwKrCs%3d

You are likely to get non-working boards the first few times you attempt this on your own. If you do need to roll your own board to get ready for a commercial product then Sparkfun has some good tutorials to get you started. 
https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/category/2

Answer (score 0):

You will find some difficulties soldering QFN Packages since the pad area is mostly under the component itself.  Usually, a reflow oven is used to mount those types of packages to a PCB.  The capacitor can be soldered easily but you need to let enough area for the solder to simultaneously heat the PCB pad and capacitor pin.

But in general, you will need to heat up the parts individually to be able to remove them one by one if you plan on removing them. Again, you will need to make sure to not exceed the thermal capability of the part which is usually 125C-150C.